# gitlab-runner Checking for jobs... failed . Error decoding json payload unexpected EOF

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I install a gitlab-runner in Windows 10

When the Gitlab CI start to execute the job which the gitlab-runner is supposed to work on, sometimes, the gitlab-runner will yell the following logs:

> time="2017-12-26T16:39:49+08:00" level=warning msg="Checking for jobs... failed" runner=96856a1d status="Error decoding json payload unexpected EOF"

It is really annoying.

I have to restart the gitlab-runner and it could work again.

The following is the content of config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 30

[[runners]]
  name = "windows docker runner"
  url = "http://my-gitlab.internal.example.com:9090/"
  token = "abcdefg1c39f10e869625c2118e"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running in [debugmode](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/commands/README.md#running-in-debug-mode) (stop service first) to get more info about the error.